# Genereic LinkedStack/ Towers of Hanoi (non-recursive)

Tags: java, generics, stack

The Assignment fro my data structures class is. Using the generic `LinkedStack` and `Node` classes provided, as well as the provided `TowersJob` class, solve the *Towers of Hanoi* problem non-recursively (write the `trn()` method in the file `TowersNonRecursive` by using a stack of `TowersJobs`).

Test it on enough inputs (and verify your results with the “mystery” class) to be sure you have it working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TowersNonRecursive
{
    public static void tnr(int n, String left, String middle, String right)
    {
        // WRITE THIS METHOD--NO RECURSION, USE A STACK OF TOWERSJOBS (USE THE GENERIC STACK)
        int start = 1, aux =3, end  =2;
        LinkedStack <T>t = new LinkedStack<T>();
        TowersJob tj = new TowersJob(n, left, middle, right);
        t.push(tj);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        String left, middle, right;

        System.out.print("Enter n:  ");
        n = kbd.nextInt();
        kbd.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter String 'left':  ");
        left = kbd.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter String 'middle':  ");
        middle = kbd.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter String 'right':  ");
        right = kbd.nextLine();
        System.out.println();

        tnr(n, left, middle, right);

    } 
}
```

My question would be how do I create a stack of `TowerJobs` in the `trn()` method

here are the other classes

```
public class LinkedStack<T>
{
    private Node<T> top;

    public LinkedStack()
    {
        top = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        if (top == null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public T peek()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new RuntimeException("Peek attempted on empty stack");
        else
            return top.data;
    }

    public void push(T m)
    {
        Node<T> temp; 
        temp = new Node<T>();
        temp.data = m;

        temp.next = top;
        top = temp;
    }

    public T pop()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new RuntimeException("Pop attempted on empty stack");
        else
        {
            T temp = top.data;
            top = top.next;
            return temp;


        }
    }

}



public class Node<T>
{
    public T data;
    public Node next;

}

public class TowersJob
{
    public int n;
    public String left;
    public String middle;
    public String right;

    public TowersJob (int n, String left, String middle, String right)
    {
        this.n = n;
        this.left = left;
        this.middle = middle;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String t = "TowersJob: n = " + n;
        t = t + ", left = " + left; 
        t = t + ", middle = " + middle; 
        t = t + ", right = " + right; 
        return t;
    }

}
```

Im totally lost on this assignment. My first issue would be initializing and creating the Stack of TowersJob in the first place.

Comment: Change `LinkedStack <T>` to `LinkedStack <TowerJobs>`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
LinkedStack <T>t = new LinkedStack<T>();
```

write

```
LinkedStack <TowerJobs>t = new LinkedStack<TowerJobs>();
```